# How do you manage SSH info?

Tags: security, ssh

I am a developer and work with a couple of servers. Is there any program that allows you to securely save SSH (and other related info, such as KVM access, etc) securely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are asking for a program that is essentially a secure vault for your usernames and passwords, so seeing as the others have answered in a different way, I will say that we used to use KeePass: http://keepass.info/

If you are the only person accessing the password DB then you should have no issues, but as we had multiple people accessing it was infuriating when one person had a lock on the DB, so we moved to PasswordManager Pro: http://www.manageengine.com/products/passwordmanagerpro/

Hope this answers your question!

Comment: I use Keepass too. Newer versions allow for simultaneous access ;-)

Answer (score 2):

For SSH just use the config file. Default for ssh client on unix like sytems (i.e. ubuntu) is "$HOME/.ssh/config" and syntax is documented on man 5 ssh_config.

Example:

```
Host                     foo
Hostname                 10.20.0.1
User                     oper
IdentityFile             %d/.ssh/myoperid_rsa
```

then use:

```
ssh foo
```

And you get the same as:

```
ssh oper@10.20.0.1 -i ~/.ssh/myoperid_rsa
```

For security concerning, just be sure that ssh key files and config file are only readable by you (chmod 600).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of information you want to securely save securely (joke regarding your question), but [ssh-keys](http://pkeck.myweb.uga.edu/ssh/) and ssh config file do the job.